# Getting LazyInitializationException within in a @Transactional method

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional, lazy-initialization, hibernate-4.x

I’m getting this exception when I access this method from my controller:

> {"status":"failure","exception":"LazyInitializationException","exceptionMessage":"failed
>   to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   org.mainco.subco.lessonplan.domain.LessonPlan.classrooms, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session","errorMessage":"failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   org.mainco.subco.lessonplan.domain.LessonPlan.classrooms, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session"}

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired
private ThirdPartyService m_thirdPartySvc;

…

@RequestMapping(value = "/launch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional
public String launchLti(final @RequestParam String assignmentId,
                        final Model model,
                        final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response,
                        final Principal principal) throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    final subcoAuthenticationUser auth = (subcoAuthenticationUser) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    String nextPage = null;
    final User user = m_userSvc.findById(auth.getId());

    // Provision the assignment in ThirdParty if not already done so
    final Assignment assmt = m_lessonPlanDao.getAssignment(assignmentId);
    if (!assmt.isSentToThirdParty())
    {
        m_thirdPartySvc.sendAssignment(assignmentId);
    }   // if
```

Is the `@Transactional` annotation unnecessary?  Especially since I already have it on my `@Service` class…

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ThirdPartyServiceImpl implements ThirdPartyService
{

    @Override
    public void sendAssignment(final String assignmentId)
    {
        final Assignment assignment = m_lessonPlanDao.getAssignment(assignmentId);
        if (isThirdPartyAssignment(assignment))
        {
            final String ThirdPartyPromptId = assignment.getTocItem().getThirdPartyPromptId();
            // Gather the teacher id
            final LessonPlan lessonPlan = m_lessonPlanDao.getLessonPlan(assignment.getLessonPlan().getId());
            final String teacherId = lessonPlan.getOwnerId();
            // Gather the students who have been assigned this assignment
            final List<Classroom> classes = lessonPlan.getClassrooms();
            // Send one request for each class assignment
            for (final Classroom classroom : classes)
            {
```

The error occurs on the `for (final Classroom classroom : classes)` line.  I have `@Transactional` everywhere, yet I’m getting this `LazyInitializationException`.  Why?  And how do I create a transaction so that I can run my method?

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, and JPA 2.1 on JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  If upgrading any of these would solve my problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Transactional` boundary is being respected by application during runtime. You can find this out by calling: `TransactionSynchronizationManager#isActualTransactionActive()`

Add some code to print out the value of above method. If it's false, then maybe you need to make sure the `component-scan` is set up right.

Example: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.application.dao" />`

This would totally miss the classes in the `com.application.service` package.

Comment: If the component scan weren't working, the @Autowired "private ThirdPartyService m_thirdPartySvc;" declaration would come up null, correct?  But that is not what is happening.  The method is getting invoked and then I'm getting that exception within the method.

Comment: What do you get for: `TransactionSynchronizationManager#isActualTransactionActive()`

Comment: It returns false.  The problem is with the contexts -- root vs web application  ... I will write up a more detailed answer soon.